# Twitter bootstrap style inheritance with jinja2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, template-engine, jinja2

I'm developing an web app with Google app engine that uses jinja2 as a template engine.

I'm my `base.html` file i have a `<link>` tag for CSS.

Now i have a another file `front.html` that extends the first file . It has the `{% extends 'base.html' %}` block and the code is in a block `{% block content %}`  ....... `{% endblock %}`.

In the second file, the CSS style won't apply. Any ideas how to fix it ?

To be more precise:
base.html :

`<head>

    <link ... >

< /head>

<body>

 {% block content %}

 {% endblock %}

</body>`

front.html:
`{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

....

{% endblock %}`

The style from the  tag won't apply to the block.

Comment: You should try and provide more of each of the files involved, just knowing that ``front.html`` extends from ``base.html`` isn't enough to answer your question accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out . The path to the `front.html` was something like `/path1/path2` while for the `base.html` the path was `/path1`. So it did not link corectly.

As a solution you can make a block on the link tag and the override it something like:

`{% block stylesheet %}

<link href="path1/something.css">

{% endblock %}`

and in the child you have
`{% block stylesheet %}

<link href="/path1/path2/something.css">

{% endblock %}`

Or, you could put a path in the `app.yaml` file.